# Airflow 2.6.3: [2023-08-13T06:50:44.937+0000] {manager.py:922} INFO - Login Failed for user: admin

Tags: airflow, version, new-operator

I recently upgraded to Airflow version to 2.6.3 and experiencing login failure error. Anyone came across this error after version upgrades? Please help.

[2023-08-13T06:50:44.937+0000] {manager.py:922} INFO - Login Failed for user: admin

airflow db init
airflow db upgrade